# highland.js: map function not working as intended

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, highland.js

Learning the ropes of [highland.js](http://highlandjs.org/), a node stream manager.

Attempting to do something pretty basic:

```
_ = require("highland")

doubled = (x)->
    return x*2

_.map(doubled, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and getting no output

when I instead run

```
_ = require("highland")

doubled = (x)->
    return x*2

console.log(_.map(doubled, [1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

I get the following output:

```
{ domain: null,
  _events: { newListener: [Function], removeListener: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  id: '200471',
  paused: true,
  _incoming: [],
  _outgoing: [],
  _consumers: [],
  _observers: [],
  _send_events: false,
  _send: [Function],
  source:
   { domain: null,
     _events: { newListener: [Function], removeListener: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     id: '060326',
     paused: true,
     _incoming: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, {} ],
     _outgoing: [],
     _consumers: [ [Circular] ],
     _observers: [],
     _send_events: false } }
```

which looks to me like a stream that doesn't have any content in it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` turns one stream into another stream. You need to use something like `reduce` or `each` or `toArray` to collect the results.

It's also possible for a stream to be paused, in which case it won't produce any output until you `resume` it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach it:

```js
_ = require("highland")

doubled = (x)->
    return x*2

_([1, 2, 3, 4]).map(doubled).map(String).pipe(process.stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Still learning Highland.js myself, but the docs say that the streams are [lazily-evaluated](http://highlandjs.org/#laziness), so they're not started until a **thunk**ing operator is called, such as `.each()`, `.apply()`, `.toArray()`, `.pipe()`, or `.resume()` - they're all marked "This function causes a **thunk**." in the docs.

You probably want to do something like (apologies if this doesn't make sense, I don't know CoffeeScript)

```coffee
_ = require("highland")

doubled = (x)->
    return x*2

_.map(doubled, [1, 2, 3, 4]).toArray((array) -> /* Array is available here */ )
```

Within the callback function (at the `/*Array is available here*/`), the array is passed in with the doubled values, like they do in [the main example](http://highlandjs.org/#arrays).